# CSS exercise on box model - not able to solve

Tags: html, css

I am trying to solve an online CSS& HTML exercise with an expected result given a set of constraints. The expected solution is imaged below.

The constraints are the type of properties and their occurrences that we can use

- div (4)
- display (1)
- margin (2)
- padding (2)
- border (2)

Also the suggested values for the above (except display) can be chosen from one of the following only.

- 1px solid (2)
- 20px (1)
- 10px (2)
- 5px (1)

[Expected Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EANh8.png)

My code attempt for HTML and CSS as follows. it doesnt align the same way. i used only the values stated

HTML:

```
<div>Hello</div>
<div></div>
<div class="some-div">
    <div class="world-div">
        World
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.some-div{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.world-div{
    display: inline;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: this exercise can be found here. the solution can be run and submitted here https://wakata.io/learn/html/ex/htmlcss-10

Comment: Seems relevant: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822) Show what (and that) you have tried before asking for help.

Comment: Sure. i will post my attempt. Thanks for that link. This is not an assignment from school or any paid course though. I am just trying free online exercises randomly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, Yeah. I solved it, but it was a strange and confusing exercise, as it gave you more parts than you need.

```css
.wrap{
display: flex;
}
.hello{
}
.world{
border: 1px solid;
padding: 10px;
margin: 20px;
}
.remaining {
border: 1px solid;
padding: 5px;
margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="world">World</div>
  <div clas="leftover"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for the given assignment.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn">
    Login
  </button>

   <button type="button" class="btn">
     Signup
  </button>
   <button type="button" class="btn">
     Guest
  </button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
  height:100vh;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.btn{
  border:1px solid #333;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#333;
  background-color:#fff;
  box-shadow:2px 3px 0px 0px #000;
  font-size:15px;
  transition:all 0.2s linear;
  cursor:pointer;
}
.btn:hover{
  transform:translate(-5px,-5px);
}
.btn:not(:last-child){
  margin-right:20px;
}
```

Codepen link for the same is https://codepen.io/pranaysharma995/full/RwPpzKz

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned. Thats the login page. you can go in as guest and see the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
}

.world-container{
  margin: 20px;
}

.world{
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class="hello">
    Hello
  </div>
  <div class='world-container'>
    <div class="world">
      World
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this might solve your issue.
[Here is the codepen link](https://codepen.io/thoughtlessmind/pen/XWbMvWo?editors=1100)